# Cross Domain SQL Server Logins Using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cross-domain, windows-authentication

I have a SQL Server 2005 named instance using Windows Authentication with domain groups serving as logins. The domain structures are as follows:

```
      Forest1                Forest2
      /      \                  |
Domain1       Domain2        Domain3
```

Objects are organized in the following domains:

**Forest1.Domain1**

- Users
- Global Groups

**Forest1.Domain2**

- SQL Server Instance
- Domain Local Groups (serving as Logins)

**Forest2.Domain3**

- Users
- Global Groups

All my users exist in `Domain1` and `Domain3` but the SQL Server box exists in `Domain2`. As such, my logins are  domain groups in `Domain2`. When a user in `Domain1` is added to a domain local group in `Domain2` and attempts to connect using TCP/IP protocol to the SQL Server instance, he receives the following error message:

> Cannot connect to <instance>. Login failed for user 'Domain1\userName'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Other things I've tried:

- If I add the user as a login
  explicitly, he can connect.
- If I add a `Domain1` global group of
  which the user is a member as a login
  explicitly, he can connect.
- If I add a `Domain1` global group of
  which the user is a member as a
  member of the `Domain2` domain local
  group used as a login, he cannot
  connect.
- **EDIT:** If I add the `Domain2` domain local group to the Demote Desktop Users group on the `Domain2` server hosting the SQL Server instance, the `Domain1` user can successfully connect to the server - I can also connect to the instance locally as the `Domain1` user (just not remotely).
- **EDIT:** If I add the `Domain2` domain local group to a local server group and create a SQL Server login for that local server group, the `Domain1` user still cannot connect to the instance remotely.
- **EDIT:** If I change the connection network protocol to "Named Pipes", the `Domain1` user can successfully connect remotely.

---

From what I understand (referencing these TechNet articles: [Group Scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [Nesting Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776499%28WS.10%29.aspx)), the domain group MUST be a domain local group in order to include users from both `Domain1` and `Domain3`.

How can I use a domain group as a SQL Server login using Windows authentication such that the domain group can contain users from both `Domain1` and `Domain3` and users can connect remotely via TCP/IP?

**MORE NOTES**

- The service account for the SQL Server named instance is a user account in `Domain1`
- SPN's have been added for the service account (including server name and alias names)

**UPDATE**

Changing the SQL Service instance service account to be in `Domain2` seems to have resolved the issue. I'll investigate further and post back my findings!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in my question update, changing the service account to be in `Domain2` resolved the issue. So what was going on?

**The Problem - Explained**

From what I can tell (also with help from a Microsoft representative), because the service account was originally a `Domain1` user, it could not determine what domain local groups the connecting user is a member of when the user is authenticating via Kerberos. The primary lead that this was a Kerberos issue was when I successfully connected using "Named Pipes" as this uses NTLM authentication.

**Overall Solution**

To bring it all together, to successfully add users from `Domain1` and `Domain3` as members of groups in `Domain2` so that the groups can be used as SQL Server logins with Windows authentication, here's a list of requirements (or at least strongly encouraged):

1. Established trust relationships between the domains

   1. At a minimum, 1 way trusts must be set up so that `Domain2` trusts `Domain1` and `Domain3`
2. Groups in `Domain2` must be scoped "Domain Local"

   1. This is so you can add users and groups from `Domain1` and `Domain3`
   2. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692%28WS.10%29.aspx) for more info
3. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to designate a non-administrative `Domain2` user as the service account identity

   1. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) documents why using a domain user account may be preferred
   2. Even though the configuration manager is supposed to add users to local SQL Server 2005 specific groups for you (i.e. SQLServer2005MSSQLUser$MY_MACHINE$MY_INSTANCE), I ran into a few instances where this wasn't the case. So just check your local groups to ensure they've been updated appropriately with your `Domain2` user account.
   3. Although SQL Server set up should automatically assign appropriate permissions for their local groups, again, I ran into a few instances where this was not the case. If this happens to you, you can reference this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28SQL.90%29.aspx#Review_NT_rights) article along with the previously mentioned article for permission requirements.
4. Configure a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server instance host (including any aliases) and the `Domain2` service account

   1. The SPN is required for mutual authentication between the client and the server host
   2. See this [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773257%28WS.10%29.aspx) article for more info
5. Depending on how you intend to use impersonation, you may want to enable the `Domain2` service account to be trusted for delegation

   1. See this [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757194%28WS.10%29.aspx) article for more info
6. Enable remote connections for the SQL Service instance
7. Finally, create logins for desired `Domain2` groups and any `Domain1` or `Domain3` members should be able to connect remotely!

**Note**

As always with any remote network activity, check your firewalls to ensure your SQL Server ports are not blocked. Although the default port is 1433, check to make sure your port is in the clear.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I met the issue as well in 2017, hard to find any solution, finally, I figure it out only for my case.

My environment,

> Forest 1 (Domain1) --- TRUST --- Forest 2(Domain2)

I have a service account in Domain2 trying to log in SQL server in Domain1 by using Windows Authentication.

And, following error message pops up.

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

The solution is simple enough, on domain1, open active directory domains and trusts tool,

> Trusts -> outgoing trusts -> properties -> authentication -> change to "Forest-wide authentication"

My problem solved.