# Connecting to different databases on different domains using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, cross-domain, database-connection, windows-authentication

I have to work with 3rd party tool that connected on different DBs/Servers to collect some data and do some work. It is not important what this app do just note that it connects to `Server1\DB1` and `Server2\DB2` on `Domain1`. Both servers use ONLY Windows Authentication (i.e. client have to connected with `IntegratedSecurity=true`). This approach works pretty well in `Domain1`. But one day we decided to move this app working on another domain (business reasons). We created mirror of `Server1\DB1` on another domain (let call it `Server1IOtherDomain\DB1`). Currently this app can work with S`erver1OtherDomain\DB1` because I run it as user of new domain and it seems everything OK. We just need support fresh version of DB on our environment. However few days ago we have recognized that connection string to `Server2\DB2` is hardcoded and we can't do the same with `Server2\DB2` (to create mirror on our `OtherDomain`). Obviously, some part of functionality is not working just because it can't reach `Server2\DB2` in `Domain1`. 
To summarize I have picture:

[image]

---

My 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to run somehow application in `OtherDomain` to have it connected to both DBs in different domains ?
2. Is it possible to make C# program that can be connected for various servers in different domains? For example using different Windows Authentication to different hosts, how to manage such cases?

Comment: please note that this app is 3rd party and I can't rebuild it. I have tried to run it as different user `runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN1\USER_NAME "App.exe"`, but this broken connection to `Server1OtherDomain\DB1`. Because running in OtherDomain I can't use old `Server1\DB1`.

Comment: are both domains  trust relationship?

Comment: If the app is third party, then this isn't a programming question, but an infrastructure question that might be better asked on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) isn't it?

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question:
It is possible to have a C# program that can be used across different domains, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/3864353) for a simple C# implementation, [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361063) for more details about cross domain authentication and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890174) for a bit more specific issue related to SQL Server and cross domain authentication.
There are steps that you will need to take to make both domains trusted by each other to allow for a connection from the one to the other, this however also opens both domains to more security concerns and such decisions need to be evaluated and made by the network administrators.

I would also recommend that you have a look [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [WindowsImpersonationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx) for examples and additional information as to how to specifically implement impersonation.