# Problems with connecting to SQL Server instance on multiinstance computer

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication

I have a computer with several SQL Server instances installed - 2008, 2012 and 2016. From this computer there is no problem to connect to any of them using Windows Authentication.

Now I try to connect to the SQL Server 2016 instance from another computer. On the server computer I've created the appropriate Windows user and SQL Server login. But when I try to connect to this instance from the different computer, the login fails.

Finally I've managed to connect to SQL Server 2016 database engine using following server name:

```
TCP:ALEXMWIN81,49602
```

But when I try to connect to the SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services, the login again fails.

Can anybody give some advice on how to connect? All instances are very important and re-installation is a problem.

Thanks in advance. Alexander Mitchenko

Comment: You should post the exact error message

Comment: Error message says that server is not avalable

Comment: Are you using dynamic ports or are you setting them to specific ports?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2466860/how-to-determine-and-change-the-port-of-an-ssas-instance

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> On the server computer I've created the appropriate Windows user and SQL Server login.

This makes it sound like you are creating a local windows login on the server machine. It should be noted that in order to use Windows authentication both your connecting machine and the server need to be on the same domain.

Creating a SQL login is a separate authentication process called "SQL Server Authentication". When you use this methodology you connect with a username and password only. For this process you would connect by putting the login credentials into a connection string.

Do you have multiple domains? This can cause problems.
[Cross Domain SQL Server Logins Using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890174/cross-domain-sql-server-logins-using-windows-authentication)

Does the SQL instance expose all the required ports to the internal network?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Is the server running a Windows Firewall?

What software are you connecting from?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning - 1 .both computers are in the same workgroup, all ports are exposed Firewall is down and I am connecting using MS SQL Server Management Studio, Please take in mind that I can connect to database engine (see before) but cannot connect to Analysis Services

Comment: The main point of my question is that all three instanses are using standard ports and actual connection on my guess is made through virtual ports - for database engine it is 49602, but what the port is for Analiysis Service instance?