# Impersonate Windows user accessing MSSQL server from a different domain

Tags: c#, sql-server, cross-domain, impersonation

Using C# I'm trying connecting to a MSSQL server using Windows user impersonation from a Windows service. MSSQL server is in domain A and the service is in domain B. From this service of domain B I was able to impersonate a Windows user (domain A) from MSSQL server using LogonUser Windows API with logonType=9 (new credentials) and using WindowsIdentity.Impersonate to create the impersonation context. The Windows user is configured to have access to MSSQL server.

The problem is the exception received:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an
>   untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

How this problem can be solved? I hope there is a solution for this in the code, programmatically, or in MSSQL configuration regarding trusted domains, or both.

```
integratedSecurity = true
logonType = 9

using (new Impersonation(domainName, userName, password, integratedSecurity, logonType))
{
  connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = host;
  connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = database;
  connectionStringBuilder.Pooling = false;
  connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = integratedSecurity;
  connectionStringBuilder.ConnectTimeout = connectionTimeout;

  using (Connect = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString)) <--- exception
  {
```

Comment: Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47344013/6305294

Comment: It seems interesting, I will checking it.

Comment: It works! Please add your answer to let me marking it as accepted.

Comment: Glad that it has helped. Please up-vote the linked answer, since it has helped you resolve your problem.